# What is the minimum needed to setup MSDEPLOY ? Or will using file copy from VS work just as well ?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, deployment, msdeploy

I am coming from years of XCOPY deployment so I am trying to make steps to make deploying to the various servers more efficient. When I have used hosted services like AZURE I know it would give me the information I need to put in the publish/webDeploy box to make everything just work.

I have a blank Windows server 2012 machine with IIS. What do I do to activate it so that I can deploy from my Visual Studio ? Where do I get the URL for MSDEPLOY from ?

And a related question.. Will using file copy option in Publish be just as good as MSDEPLOY for my basic requirements?  All I want to be able to do in the end is select a Profile from VS and publish to the dev/test/prod machine and use XML transforms for the web.config.

Comment: See http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy and http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy

Comment: I read everything there and installed web deploy.. But what next? How do I know what parameters to use in VS Publish to speak to the web server after I install this ?